# Multifile select using File Upload which is inside Repeater

Tags: c#, jquery

I am using `jquery` multifile to select multiple files. Code as below :

```
$(function ($) {
     multiFile();
});

function multiFile() {
     $('#<%= fuData.ClientID %>').multifile();
}
```

It is working fine. But, now another `FileUpload` control is inside `Repeater`. So, how to use it for multifile select ? It will create new ids for each `Repeater` Item. So, how do i assign reference of it here ??

Comment: `$('#<%= fuData.ClientID %>,your new id').multifile();`

Comment: @Justcode, But `Fileupload` control is inside `Repeater` so of course, it wont find that id.

Comment: can't you inspect and find id of it?

Comment: for one i can write but wat for number of `Repeater` items.

Comment: you said there is one another file upload inside repeater. so, you can write like `$('repeaterclass input[type=file]')`